# Converting Excel Date Serial Number to Date using JavaScript in All timezone

Tags: javascript, date-conversion

I have tried to convert excel date to javascript date using this function but it only works UTC+ timezone and not working UTC- timeZone

UTC- timezone it takes one day before from the excel date and if you change 25569 to 25568 its work only UTC- timezone

```
function ExcelDateToJSDate(serial) {
   var utc_days  = Math.floor(serial - 25569);
   var utc_value = utc_days * 86400;                                        
   var date_info = new Date(utc_value * 1000);

   var fractional_day = serial - Math.floor(serial) + 0.0000001;

   var total_seconds = Math.floor(86400 * fractional_day);

   var seconds = total_seconds % 60;

   total_seconds -= seconds;

   var hours = Math.floor(total_seconds / (60 * 60));
   var minutes = Math.floor(total_seconds / 60) % 60;

   return new Date(date_info.getFullYear(), date_info.getMonth(), date_info.getDate(), hours, minutes, seconds);
}
```

Comment: can you provide test cases or example input and output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the below function we can convert excel date to javascript date in all timezone.

```
ExcelDateToJSDate(serial) {
                 var hours = Math.floor((serial % 1) * 24);
                 var minutes = Math.floor((((serial % 1) * 24) - hours) * 60)
                 return new Date(Date.UTC(0, 0, serial, hours-17, minutes));
        }
```